# Two SQL have slight difference, query efficiency is very different however, why？

Tags: sql, oracle

The sql1 query has been waiting, the sql2 query is quite fast.And why?
The c table has about 40,000 records and the field col1 is null mostly.

The first condition of the sql1 and the third condition or the second condition and the third condition query are very fast, but when the three conditions are queried together, it becomes slower and has been waiting. Is it a bug?

sql1:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id FROM a a
                        JOIN b b ON b_id=id
                        JOIN c c ON c_id=id
                        JOIN d d ON d_id=id
WHERE c.col1='col1'
  AND c.col_date <= TO_DATE('2019-05-14 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
  AND c.col_date >= TO_DATE('2019-01-14 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

sql2

```
SELECT a.id, b.id FROM a a
                        JOIN b b ON b_id=id
                        JOIN c c ON c_id=id
                        JOIN d d ON d_id=id
WHERE nvl(c.col1, '')='col1'
  AND c.col_date <= TO_DATE('2019-05-14 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
  AND c.col_date >= TO_DATE('2019-01-14 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

Comment: What conditions are you talking about?

Comment: Cold/hot data? Have you run both queries several times?

Comment: cvl(c.col1, '') = nvl(c.col1, '') ?? Perhaps you have a functional index on `nvl(c.col1, '')`

Comment: Is this a homework question? Sounds like a homework question?

Comment: @Peter4499 doesn't look like a homework question to me, please just go past if you aren't willing to add something useful.

Comment: `cvl(c.col1, '')`, I presume it was a typo, but `nvl(c.col1, '')` never makes sense in Oracle. An empty string will always be treated as `null`.

Comment: Don't really know why but I can suggest adding `WHERE c.col IS NOT NULL` as another condition to the slower one and see if it makes a difference.. if `c.col` is mostly `NULL` as you say then I think it should make a difference

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan you're right

Comment: @GordonLinoff  
The first condition refers to `c.col1='col1`,  
the second refers to  `AND c.col_date <= TO_DATE('2019-05-14 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')`
the third refers to `AND c.col_date >= TO_DATE('2019-01-14 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')`

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have a `functional index` on `nvl(c.col1, '')` while the column `col1`has no index on it.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not a "bug" in the usual sense of term.  It is simply a case where the optimizer is not choosing the right path.

Consider that `c` is really big and `a` is really small, and that you have an index where the first column is `c(col1)`.

The first query attempts to use this index.  But say table `c` is really big and `col1` is spread through all the data pages.  So, all the data needs to be read, but you are doing it through the index which slows things down.  If the table is bigger than available memory, you might get thrashing.

The second query cannot use this index.  So, it finds another execution path.  It decides that reading `a` is the best path.  `a` is small and the other tables contribute little.  It can go directly to the matching rows in `c` -- and then apply the filtering conditions.

For various reasons based on sizing estimates, Oracle may think the first approach is superior to the second, even when it is not.  Optimization is hard.

The above is only intended to provide one scenario trying to explain why something like this is happening.  The optimizer generally works well, but there is always room for improvement.